# Web.py: passing variables into <iframe>

Tags: python, iframe, web.py

Is it possible to pass a varible into and out `<iframe>`?
The problem is that i have data display in `<iframe>`, but all controls and data-sending / recieving scripts in parent frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to give the `iframe` values on page load, then you can pass the value as a `GET` parameter in the `iframe`'s URL. If you want to send values back and forth after that (and both the parent and child are on the same domain, as you stated), then you can use JavaScript. For example:

```js
// in parent page
function receiveDataFromIFrame(data) {
    console.log("Received data from iframe:", data);
}
```

```js
// in child page
function onLoad() {
    var data = "data from iframe";
    window.parent.receiveDataFromIFrame(data);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i guessed so: but the main problem is that i have to make lots of ajax requests in both directions.

Comment: @Alex: Are the parent and child pages on the same domain?

Comment: @Alex: I added an example of how you might use JavaScript to communicate between the frames.

Comment: nice... ty... my bad - couldn't work out such an easy snippet